# Oracle find total profit for each month in a certain year

Tags: sql, oracle

### Question:

For each month in 2014, display the total profit (i.e. using the attributes purchasedPrice and agreedPrice) generated from car sales only.

Tables:

### Car

```
(VIN, dateAcquired, yearBuilt, purchasedPrice, askingPrice, currentMileage, modelNo)
```

### Sales Transaction

```
(VIN, custID, agentID, dateOfSale, agreedPrice)
```

### My incorrect code:

```
select c.dateacquired, st.agreedprice - c.purchasedprice as "Total Profit" 
from salestransaction st, car c
where c.VIN = st.VIN
and extract(year from c.dateacquired) = '2014'
group by extract(month from c.dateacquired), st.agreedprice - c.purchasedprice;
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I am getting the following error:

> not a GROUP BY expression at line 01

Comment: Are you getting an error message, incorrect output, or something else? Please show us what is going wrong.

Comment: try replacing the `c.dateacquired` in the select clause with `extract(month from c.dateacquired)`

Comment: Sorry @Politank-Z, edited my post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- The profit is made when you sell the car (not when it is aquired).
- You need to `SUM` all the profits to get the total profit.
- When using `GROUP BY`, you need to `SELECT` either the exact statements in the `GROUP BY` or use aggregate functions.

Like this:

```
SELECT TRUNC( s.dateOfSale, 'MM' ) AS month_aquired,
       SUM( st.agreedprice - c.purchasedprice ) as "Total Profit" 
FROM   salestransaction st,
       car c
WHERE  c.VIN = st.VIN
AND    EXTRACT( year FROM s.dateOfSale ) = 2014
GROUP BY
       TRUNC( s.dateOfSale, 'MM' );
```

or you can replace `TRUNC( s.dateOfSale, 'MM' )` with `EXTRACT( month FROM s.dateOfSale )` at the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Columns in `SELECT` list which are not aggregate functions should match your group by expression accurately.

This means `c.dateacquired` does not equal `extract(month from c.dateacquired)`, thus giving you the error.

You would like to group by months, yet you try to select the exact, not truncated `date`.

Correct code assuming that you wish to select the month:

```
select extract(month from c.dateacquired), st.agreedprice - c.purchasedprice as "Total Profit" 
from salestransaction st, car c
where c.VIN = st.VIN
and extract(year from c.dateacquired) = '2014'
group by extract(month from c.dateacquired), st.agreedprice - c.purchasedprice;
```

This is just a fix to your query, but I'm thinking the result would still not be what you're looking for. You probably wanted to use aggregate function `sum()` on that total.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM c.dateacquired), SUM(st.agreedprice - c.purchasedprice) AS "Total Profit" 
FROM salestransaction st
INNER JOIN car c ON st.VIN = c.VIN
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM c.dateacquired) = '2014'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM c.dateacquired)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is the fix to my query, however, my output is a little different from what is expected. I am seeing multiple months with different values for total profit. EG: month 1 appears twice, first one with a value of 3000 as profit, and the next with 6000. How will I go about joining (sum) these ?